# check the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^2(n+1)}$

Tags: analysis

To conclude if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^2(n+1)}$ converges,could I use the Ratio test,which is:

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite series with non-zero terms.

-If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$,the series converges

-If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$,the series diverges

-the test is incoclusive,if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$

or do I have to use the  Dirichlet's test,to check the convergence,because of the presence of $(-1)$ at the sum?

Comment: Neither. Write down the first few terms of the series, and things may become clear.

Comment: It is $$0+\frac{2}{n^2(n+1)}+0+\frac{2}{n^2(n+1)}+\dots$$.

So,if we would take the partial sum,it would be equal to $\frac{2n}{n^2(n+1)}=\frac{2}{n(n+1)} \to 0$.

So,can we conclude something from that?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Does the series converge at $0$ ? Or have I done something wrong??

Comment: There is no "$x$" so there is no "converges at." The series converges.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I haven't understood it.Isn't the series equal to $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$,where $s_n$ is the partial sum??

Comment: Just for your legitimate curiosity, the summation converges to $-2+\frac{\pi ^2}{12}+\log (4)$

Comment: Sure, the that is the definition of sum of the series. But it is a single series, so either it converges (and it does) or it doesn't converge. Either the limit exists or it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the  comparison test:

$$\left|\frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^2(n+1)}\right|\le \frac{2}{n^2(n+1)}\le \frac{2}{n^3}$$
and the Riemann series 
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^3}$$
is convergent. Conclude.

Comment: I understand!!!Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: If we would take the partial sum,it would converge to $0$.So could we also conclude something from that ?

Comment: No the patial sum doesn't converge to $0$. In fact if we denote $S_n$ the partial sum the $S_{2n}\ge S_2=\frac1{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^2(n+1)}=2\sum_{n \ even} \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}\le 2\sum_{n \ even} \frac{1}{n} \cdot (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})\le 2\sum_{n \ even} (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}) $$

$$2\sum_{n \ even} (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}) \le 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}) \le 2$$

So, the series converge.

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: And something else..If we would take the partial sum,it would converge to $0$.So could we also conclude something from that ?

Comment: Let $s_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^2(n+1)}$. This partial sum does not converge to zero because every term is $\ge 0$ and we have terms $>0$. We conclude that sum is less or equal to 2...